# Group multiple undo levels into on batch in TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

I am writing a custom plugin for TinyMCE.  One of the new buttons makes a number of DOM manipulations in the document.  The default undo behavior creates a few undo levels in the middle of the changes.  If the user hits the undo button after using the plugin, he/she then sees a document with the operation partially reversed and really not in a proper state.

It looks like there used to be a pair of instance commands called mceBeginUndoLevel / mceEndUnoLevel (removed in version 3.3) that let a developer start/end a large undo batch that would be undone in a single operation....but I don't see anything in the docs that replaces that feature.

Some forum postings suggest using editor.undoManager.add() as a replacement, and that works for cases where you want **more** levels of undo during an operation, but I actually want less.

There is also a undoManager.onBeforeAdd event that you can hook into, but looking at the source for the undoManager, I don't think that hooking there will let you abort an undo snapshot.

So, is there a proper way to batch undo operations that I'm not seeing using the existing API?  If not, my only other option seems to be patching the undoManager to allow the onBeforeAdd hook to abort a snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest overwriting the current UndoManager. It is just a rather small file.
That's what we needed to do in order to suppress the creation of some unwanted undosteps.

Comment: Thanks @Thariama, sounds like you encountered the same problem.  Glad to hear I'm not just a fool who can't read the documentation!  I have a patch in my copy of the undoManager that aborts an undo snapshot if one of the functions registered with the undoManager.onBeforeAdd event returns false...and that seems to work.  The only thing is that I would rather not have a custom version of the TinyMCE source to make future upgrades easier.

Comment: I understand your concerns, we had the same. But we didn't alter the tinymce source code. All we did was to add the modified Undomanagercode at the end of our own plugin, which makes it easier to activate/deactivate the special undo handling.